# Devexpress xtrareport doesn't show any thing in my print

Tags: c#, printing, devexpress, datasource

i want to print a report using xtrareport so i pass my datasource as you can see here :

```
Report.Material.MRC report = new MRC();
            List<MaterialRequestContractor> lst=new List<MaterialRequestContractor>();
            lst.Add(_materialRequestContractorRepository.Get().ToList().First());
            report.DataSource =lst;

            // Show the print preview. 
            ReportPrintTool pt = new ReportPrintTool(report);
            pt.ShowPreview();
```

In my report design i add my Model as an objectmodel

[image]

But the print doesn't show any data  .
[image]

Comment: maybe you have to set the data member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should using object binding source :

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument7547